# Watson Conversation Engine Parallel Intents Processing

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I have a conversation service with intents and entities. I don't really have a dialog flow as my conversation agent would have to respond to a query which is not tiered or rather have a cadence.

For e.g.

Intent1

Intent2

...

Intent n

These are parallel intents which could respond to a question. 
What I get on dialog service is a tiered workflow, Start ->Intent 1 -> Intent2

Without Intent1, I cannot go beyond any of the flows.

Kindly advice if I am missing anything here.

Another query related is does natural language classifier service scale to return a response similar to conversation engine? What I wanted was "what is weather in Los Angeles" and it gives me back information as "Temperature" =>Intent and Entity @City=Los Angeles. Assuming that I have list of cities in my Entity City.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: **RTFM**. Dialog indeed has the ability to setup parallel intents. Clicking on + at the bottom kind of setsup parallel intents. CLicking on + sign on the right corner allows you to setup intent cadence. I observe that IBM did a good job of copying of what Microsoft did with Luis here. Looks clean with the User interface. When parallel intents are setup, you text responds back with a % match and with that you can make a genuine decision.